# Matplotlib not listening to font choices

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am unable to avoid an error in matplotlib regarding font choice. Whenever I try to plot on a remote machine in Linux I get the following error:

```
/home/josh/anaconda/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:1236:
UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['Arial'] not found. 
Falling back to Bitstream Vera Sans 
(prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

I have edited my `.matplotlibrc` file (just in case, in two locations):

- `.matplotlib/.matplotlibrc`
- `.config/matplotlib/.matplotlibrc`

Where I added the following lines:

```
backend: Agg
font.family        : serif
font.serif         : Times, Palatino, New Century Schoolbook, Bookman, Computer Modern Roman
font.sans-serif    : Helvetica, Avant Garde, Computer Modern Sans serif
font.cursive       : Zapf Chancery
font.monospace     : Courier, Computer Modern Typewriter
text.usetex        : true
```

Still, `matplotlib` keeps complaining about `Arial`. Why? (note this is when running a script with `python my_script.py`) with no IPython involved.

Comment: Added the seaborn tag.  If you are not using straight matplotlib you should indicate what extension layer you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using seaborn and don't have Arial installed, this will happen (I'm actually currently in the process of making this work better). Best solution for the time being would be to call

```
sns.set(font="serif")
```

After importing seaborn and before plotting.

Comment: Thanks -- Has there been a solution since then? I recently upgraded `seaborn` from master with no success.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I ended up tracking the problem down to a bug in matplotlib. It should be fixed in 1.4...

Comment: What is sns? How would I set Arial if available on my system?

Comment: Seaborn is most commonly imported as sns.

Answer (score 3):

from [the documentation (see method description for `set_family` or `set_name`)](http://matplotlib.org/api/font_manager_api.html)

> Real font names are not supported when text.usetex is True.

Perhaps you should use a font family like 'serif', 'sans-serif', 'cursive', 'fantasy', or 'monospace' if you'd like to be able to use TeX.

Comment: Thanks, although I am not sure I follow. Where am I failing to specify a font family like the ones you mentioned?  What exactly do I need to change in my `.matplotlibrc`?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code in which you are specifying 'Arial'.

Comment: I am not setting it myself. I wonder if this is coming from importing `seaborn`.

Comment: seaborn indeed overrides the fonts. @user815423426